# SharePoint - web-services to build a custom file-list, up and download?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, mfc

I'm building a SharePoint mini-client.

I need to show a list of folders and files inside that folder.
Then I need to upload a file and download a file.

Which SharePoint web-services should I use?
P.S. The client is bad. They don't want to install anything on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you will need the following methods:

- `GetListItems` from the [Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists_methods.aspx) Web service (retrieving list items)
- `Copy` from the [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvccopy.aspx) Web service (uploading and downloading documents)